# To increase application badge number on receiving push notification using pushwoosh

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am using pushwoosh portal to send push notification and i want to increase the application badge number on receiving push notification. And i am using following method of Pushwoosh sdk to send badge number to server.

```
- (void) pw_setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:(NSInteger) badgeNumber
```

But on Pushwoosh portal , there is only one option to set badge number. if i assign an integer value as badge number then it shows on app icon on receiving push notification and if i do not assign any value then it removes badge from app icon.

Question: My problem is that what is the roll of that badge value which i sent from code to pushwoosh server?
when and where will that value be used?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you would like to send incremental badge values instead of integer values.
In Pushwoosh you should simply add the "+" before the value of the badge number. For instance if you send your notifications through API, you should simply add the "ios_badges":"+1" to your json request.